# Retrofit two version

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, retrofit

I got module that use new Retrofit 2, and library in aar that depend on Retrofit 1.9

so my `build.gradle` `dependencies` looks like

```
compile project(':shop') // Module depend on retrofit2

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'
compile(name: 'dotpay-sdk', ext: 'aar') // Lib depend on retrofit1.9
```

however when i call method from lib i get `NoClassDefFoundError` most likely from `RestAdapter`.

is there option to use to version of same library?

Comment: try `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a new release of the Retrofit it will be not easy to use both libraries at the same project, due they will cause you conflicts because they have the same package. In the final release Retrofit and OkHttp will came with the version on the package. You can read more about it here: http://jakewharton.com/java-interoperability-policy-for-major-version-updates/

If you really need to use both version there is an issue with some alternatives that you can use: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1152